# WCF Service passing a filepath

Tags: c#, wcf

In my WCF I accept a parameter Filepath

I.e.
F:\BatchFiles\InputFile\SampeFile_Tabbed_WithNull.txt (This file 100% exists)

And I have this check then

```
public BatchSplitterResponse SplitFile(BatchSplitterRequest request)
        {
            //Retrieve File
            var response = new BatchSplitterResponse();
            if (request != null)
            {
                var filePath = request.FilePath;
                var numberOfRecordsPerFile = request.NumberOfRecordsPerFile;

                if (File.Exists(filePath))
                {..
}
```

When I add my WCF as a service reference to my console application and call my WCF service I keep getting an error that the file does not exist..

```
var linkService = new BatchSplitterClient("BasicHttpBinding_IBatchSplitter");
var response = linkService.SplitFile(new BatchSplitterRequest(){FilePath = @"F:\BatchFiles\InputFile\SampeFile_Tabbed_WithNull.txt",NumberOfRecordsPerFile = 1000});
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Can you log the path within your WCF service and check that it is actually valid?

Comment: Is your WCF service hosted in IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem my be in the applicationpool identity.
You need to set up your applicationpool to "ApplicationPoolIdentity"

Here is a link that explains a bit more about the subject.
http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: We don't know if @StevieB is using a service hosted in IIS or in a console application. Maybe it's a good idea to ask that!

Answer (score 0):

The user that is running your WCF service probably doesn't have access to the the "F:\" drive. This could be because it is a mounted drive or some missing/incorrect permission.